# Delete all folders except specific folders

Tags: c++, directory, boost-filesystem

I already have a boost function to delete one folder at a time. `remove_all();`

The list of folders are:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
folder4
folder5
```

I want to delete them all with my function above but keep folder2 and folder5.

Comment: Couldn't you loop through the folders and check if they aren't `folder2` or `folder5`, and if not delete them?

Comment: Load the ones you want to *keep* into a std::set<std::string>, then pass that to an enhanced removal function that only removes items *not* in that set. you may have to get creative if you're recursing into subfolders.

Comment: Write a function that takes a list of "folders to keep" and compares each "perhaps delete this" with the list of "folders to keep", and if it's in the keep list, don't delete it (or write "ha ha, deleted it anyways" after deleting, of your are devious!)

Comment: I've found the answer but I can't post it yet, cause I'm a new user...

Comment: @Peteragent5 What's your problem with posting? You should be able to answer your own question, AFAIK it's at least encouraged behavior on SO.

Comment: @g-makulik The error is this: `Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 4 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.`

Comment: @Peteragent5 OK, I'll give you a +1. You should show some working code in your answer.

Comment: @g-makulik Thanks, I always love to help others. And yes the code should be up in 1 more hour

Answer (score 1):

I've actually found 2 ways how to do this.

First I put my list of folders into an array.

1st way: Used a function to find substring in my string array, then erase it.

2nd way: Used strcmp to compare with my string array, then erase the found search tag.

And here is the final code:

```
// simple_ls program form boost examples
// http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/filesystem/example/simple_ls.cpp
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 3

//  We don't want to use any deprecated features
#ifndef BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED 
#  define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
#endif
#ifndef BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED 
#  define BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
#endif

#include "boost/filesystem/operations.hpp"
#include "boost/filesystem/path.hpp"
#include "boost/progress.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;
unsigned long dir_count = 0;

void RemoveSub(string& sInput, const string& sub) {
    string::size_type foundpos = sInput.find(sub);
    if ( foundpos != string::npos )
        sInput.erase(sInput.begin() + foundpos, sInput.begin() + foundpos + sub.length());
}

int listDir(string d) {
d.erase(
remove( d.begin(), d.end(), '\"' ),
d.end()
); //Remove Quotes

if (!is_directory(d)) {
    cout << "\nNot found: " << d << endl;
    return 1;
  }
    directory_iterator end_iter;
    for (directory_iterator dir_itr(d);
        dir_itr != end_iter;
        ++dir_itr) {
            if (is_directory(dir_itr->status())) {
            ++dir_count;
            string v = dir_itr->path().filename().string();
            v.erase(
            remove( v.begin(), v.end(), '\"' ),
            v.end()
            );
            string m[] = { v };
            string mm = m[0].c_str();
            RemoveSub(mm, "folder2"); // Keep folder2
            RemoveSub(mm, "folder5"); // Keep folder5
/*
            if( strcmp(m[0].c_str(), "folder2") == 0 ) mm.erase (mm.begin(), mm.end()); // Keep folder2
            if( strcmp(m[0].c_str(), "folder5") == 0 ) mm.erase (mm.begin(), mm.end()); // Keep folder5
*/
            if(!mm.empty()) { // Remove folders
            cout << "\nRemoving: " << mm << " ...";
            remove_all(d+"/"+mm);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
string i;
cout << "\nx: Exit\n\nDelete all folders in: ";
getline(cin,i);
if(i=="X" || i=="x") return 0;
if(i.empty()) return 0;

listDir(i); //Call our function
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The heavy dependence of this solution on string manipulation makes this (1) difficult to read and (2) error-prone. You should try incorporating @WhozCraig 's hint of using a collection to store the directories you want to be saved and work more with the types and functions that boost::filesystem provides for you instead of fiddling with the string representations of the full paths.